# CSS (perhaps with Compass): Cross-browser gradient

Tags: css, background, cross-browser, gradient, compass-sass

I would like to get a gradient in CSS (perhaps through [Compass](http://compass-style.org/)) that works in every major browser, including IE7+.  Is there an easy way to do this (without writing a lot of code, and without a custom image file)?

I looked at Compass's [gradient mixin](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/css3/gradient/#mixin-linear-gradient), but it does not work with Internet Explorer.

Any ideas?  (It does not need to be Compass -- I am happy install something else.)

**Edit:** What I am trying to get is some framework (like Compass?) that generates code like what Blowsie posted that's been tested across browsers.  Basically like the [Compass gradient mixin](http://compass-style.org/docs/reference/compass/css3/gradient/#mixin-linear-gradient) I mentioned, but with IE support.  (I am a bit wary of just rolling my own SCSS mixin and pasting in blocks like Blowsie's code, because I haven't tested it and do not have the resources to do so.)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I just noticed that the current Compass beta (0.11.beta.6) has support for generating IE gradients in the [compass/css3/images](http://beta.compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/) module (which supersedes the previous gradient module), so you can generate your gradients with a total of two short commands:

```
@import "compass/css3/images";
@import "compass/utilities/general/hacks";  /* filter-gradient needs this */

.whatever {
  /* IE; docs say this should go first (or better, placed in separate IE-only stylesheet): */
  @include filter-gradient(#aaaaaa, #eeeeee);
  /* Fallback: */
  background: #cccccc;
  /* CSS 3 plus vendor prefixes: */
  @include background(linear-gradient(top, #aaaaaa, #eeeeee));
}
```

This generates the following slew of CSS:

```
.whatever {
  *zoom: 1;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FFAAAAAA', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE')";
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=0, startColorstr='#FFAAAAAA', endColorstr='#FFEEEEEE');
  background: #cccccc;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #aaaaaa), color-stop(100%, #eeeeee));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #aaaaaa, #eeeeee);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #aaaaaa, #eeeeee);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #aaaaaa, #eeeeee);
}
```

I guess I would have preferred to have the IE and non-IE gradient code in one call, but since IE's DXImageTransform gradient function is pretty limited, that is probably not possible.

Comment: Update: [Smart people say](http://www.stubbornella.org/content/2012/05/02/cross-browser-debugging-css/) you shouldn't be making gradients on IE6-IE8, as they can cause performance and layout issues. So these days I'd perhaps omit the `filter-gradient` line.

Comment: -then what you do for IE gradient, images?

Comment: Just a single-colored background (the "fallback" line above).

Comment: @JitendraVyas Add `$experimental-support-for-svg: true`

Answer (score 2):

The code I use for all browser gradients..

```
            background: #0A284B;
            background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#0A284B), to(#135887));
            background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0A284B, #135887);
            background: -o-linear-gradient(#0A284B, #135887);
            filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0A284B', endColorstr='#135887');
            zoom:1;
```

You will need to specify a height or zoom:1 to apply hasLayout to the element for this to work in ie

Answer (score -1):

While gradients are of limited complexity, they're complex enough to require what you would consider "lots of code".

Consider:

- starting colour, ending colour and the hexadecimal math required to transition between one and the other
- The number of "steps"
- The width/height of each step
- Since there is no pure CSS way of doing this, it means rendering HTML, one element for each colour/step, without messing up your existing HTML

So, no, without a plug-in that does all of this for you, it would require a bit of code, or an image.

Comment: Actually, I don't think you have to have HTML code for this.  See, for example, http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient for a way to do it.  (It's just way too verbose for my taste, so I'm looking for a way to do it programmatically with a CSS framework.)

Comment: The point that I'm trying to make is that there is no simple answer. You want one, but there isn't one. That doesn't make my answer worthy of a down-vote.

Comment: Fair enough, though "there is no pure CSS way of doing this" is just not correct (CSS 3 has gradient support) -- and recommending to generate HTML (or use JS) instead of writing extra CSS for those browsers that do not support it is questionable advice, in my opinion.