# Compass, SASS, Gradients, and IE?

Tags: internet-explorer, sass, compass-sass

So according to compass, they only support Chrome, Safari, Firefox 3.6, and Opera when it comes to gradients.

Any ideas on how to add support for IE in compass / some other workaround?

Code in:

```
  @import "compass";    
   .testgradient {
    @include background(
      linear-gradient(top left, #333, #0c0)
    );
  }
```

Code out:

```
.testgradient {

  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #00cc00));

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);

  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);

  background: -o-linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);

  background: linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

For versions of IE before IE10, you'll have to deal with IE's [gradient filter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532997%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

For IE10 and newer, the unprefixed `linear-gradient` should work<sup>[[1]](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh673532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)</sup>.  If you have trouble however, [other sites](http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/) simply use the vendor prefix `-ms-linear-gradient`.  The syntax for both versions is the same as all the other vendor-prefixed gradients.

Comment: Ok, how would I integrate that into SASS/compass so it would do it automatically?

Comment: I should add that I tried putting @import "compass/utilities/general/hacks"; 
in the second line. It didn't seem to change the output at all

I'm fairly new to this stuff, so I apologize for not knowing some of the basics

Comment: Integrating it into compass would require you to modify / extend compass itself.  If you're up for that, the info is [here](http://compass-style.org/get-involved/).  Otherwise, you'll want to just write your own mixin for IE<=9.  Info can be found on the [SASS website](http://sass-lang.com/tutorial.html)

Comment: The syntax for the unprefixed and prefixed `linear-gradient` variants isn't the same.

Comment: According to the latest W3C draft "top" or "left" is not supported by linear-gradient (http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-images-3/#linear-gradients). It should read "to bottom" or "to right". This issue should be fixed in future versions of compass (http://github.com/chriseppstein/compass/issues/965). Alternatively you can use "90deg" which should work in all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

you can simply create your own mixin, so your code would look like that:

```
@import "compass";    
@mixin myBackground ($direction, $colorList) {
    background: -ms-linear-gradient($direction, $colorList);
    @include background(linear-gradient($direction, $colorList));
}

.testgradient {
    @include myBackground(top left, (#333, #0c0));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd rather not muck through the entirety of the SASS docs, try this:

```
filter: e("progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr=${topcolor}, endColorstr=${bottomcolor},GradientType=0)");
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple linear gradients see: http://compass-style.org/reference/compass/css3/images/#mixin-filter-gradient, also see: [CSS (perhaps with Compass): Cross-browser gradient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5664957/css-perhaps-with-compass-cross-browser-gradient/31620672)

So you can use the SCSS code like that shown below:

```
 @import "compass";
   .testgradient {
    background: #333; /* Old browsers */

    @include background(
      linear-gradient(top left, #333, #0c0)
    );

    @include filter-gradient(#333, #0c0, top left); /* IE 6 - 8 */
  }
```

The above code compiles into CSS as follows:

```
.testgradient {
  background: #333;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0idXRmLTgiPz4gPHN2ZyB2ZXJzaW9uPSIxLjEiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyI+PGRlZnM+PGxpbmVhckdyYWRpZW50IGlkPSJncmFkIiBncmFkaWVudFVuaXRzPSJvYmplY3RCb3VuZGluZ0JveCIgeDE9IjAuMCIgeTE9IjAuMCIgeDI9IjEuMCIgeTI9IjEuMCI+PHN0b3Agb2Zmc2V0PSIwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzMzMzMzMyIvPjxzdG9wIG9mZnNldD0iMTAwJSIgc3RvcC1jb2xvcj0iIzAwY2MwMCIvPjwvbGluZWFyR3JhZGllbnQ+PC9kZWZzPjxyZWN0IHg9IjAiIHk9IjAiIHdpZHRoPSIxMDAlIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCUiIGZpbGw9InVybCgjZ3JhZCkiIC8+PC9zdmc+IA==');
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, color-stop(0%, #333333), color-stop(100%, #00cc00));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top left, #333333, #00cc00);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #333333, #00cc00);
  *zoom: 1;
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(gradientType=1, startColorstr='#FF333333', endColorstr='#FF00CC00');
  /* IE 6 - 8 */ }
```

Comment: So this should have been closed as a duplicate of that question?  I mean, you did swipe the answer from that other question and updated the arguments.

Comment: yes, i agree with that